# Opening a new activity: animation starts but activity is showed before the animation

Tags: android, animation, android-activity

I do:

```
startActivityForResult(i, NEW_ACTIVITY);
overridePendingTransition(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
```

The new Activity starts, but it is showed immediately... And only in a second time, it disappear and then fades in as requested. In other words, when I execute the above code, the new animation

1. flashes one time
2. disappears
3. fades in

**I don't want the step 1.**

PS: 
*fade in:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0" android:toAlpha="1.0" android:duration="750" />
```

*fade out:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0" android:toAlpha="0.0" android:duration="750" />
```

### ****Edit****

I realize that it happens ONLY when in the activity's onCreate() there is a ProgressDialog.show() command! If I show a ProgressDialog in te onCreate, this make animation to be wrong! Any Idea?

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem with your code. It looks correct to me. What I guess is, may be your activity or your app uses a theme (a default one, maybe) which also specifies a Activity animation. So you could try setting a theme to your app from Manifest and then set 
`<item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@null</item>` to your theme and see if it works.

Comment: try reverse order: first override pending animation, and then start new activity

Comment: I realize that it happens ONLY when in the activity's onCreate() there is a ProgressDialog.show() command! If I show a ProgressDialog in te onCreate, this make animation to be wrong! Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You could use an AnimationListener and in onAnimationEnd(), start Your activity.